# Flutter Stacking children in a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart

Just a quick question, I've been having issue with stacking 2 different children one on top of the other, here is the test code. Basically

```
body: Stack(
          children: [
            
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 150.0,
                  height: 150.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage('assets/testlogo.png')),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            
            TabBarView(
              children: [
                _One(),
                _Two(),
                
                
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

But the issue I am getting is that the tabs overlap the Row with the Container, something like this:

[image]

Basically what I need is to have the Container (Row) with the image on top of the TabBarView, and then the One() and Two() tab bar below without them overlapping the image. I hope I'm clear with the question and that the answer is very simple, but I couldn't get it to work properly.

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the children with Positioned(...) widget.

Comment: Not sure if I asked the question correctly, I updated the main post just to show you guys what I need. The positioned() doesn't work correctly.

Comment: then in pseudo code, `column(stack(row(container)), TabBarView)`, though I do not understand, what your Row is good for, since I only see one child, the Container. And what for do you need a Stack? If there is another, here not apparent reason, you could stack your TabBarView on top of the Container and by wrapping it in a column with a sized box as top margin, so  `stack(row(container), column(sizedBox(height: ofContainer), TabBarView))`. But still I guess you need Positioned

Comment: You might be correct, I'll try it out and guess that would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget as the child/children your `Stack` widget.

This is from the `Stack` widget [API doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) (**emphasis** added):

> Each child of a Stack widget is either positioned or non-positioned. Positioned children are those wrapped in a Positioned widget that has at least one non-null property. **The stack sizes itself to contain all the non-positioned children, which are positioned according to alignment** (which defaults to the top-left corner in left-to-right environments and the top-right corner in right-to-left environments). The positioned children are then placed relative to the stack according to their top, right, bottom, and left properties.

Since you're only using alignment in one of your children (the `Row`), the other children are just laying based on the default behavior of the `Stack` widget. so you can wrap the child in a `Positioned` widget:

```dart
body: Stack(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 150.0,
          height: 150.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/testlogo.png')),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    // Update here: wrapped with Positioned
    Positioned(
      left: 24.0,
      child: TabBarView(
        children: [
          _One(),
          _Two(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Alternatively you could wrap your children in an `Align` widget:

```dart
body: Stack(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 150.0,
          height: 150.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/testlogo.png')),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
    // Update here: wrapped with Align
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
      child: TabBarView(
        children: [
          _One(),
          _Two(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```